# Return Page/Post ID's of Child WP_Nav_Menu items

Tags: menus

Is it possible to return the Page ID of menu items?

I specifically looking to get the IDs that appear in a rollover submenu.

Comment: Return … **where**? Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks @toscho! (I know ur not real...) Let me be more descriptive... I'm looking to get the IDs from submenu items to use in the Order & Orderby Parameters of a WP_Query. The reasoning is a bit complex but was wonderding if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Hook int `'wp_nav_menu_objects'`. You get a list (an array) of all found menu items as an array. Each item is an object, and each one has a property named `ID`. That's the ID of the original object if it was a post object.

In your filter callback just iterate over these items, collect the IDs and use them later in your custom query.

- See [How to var_dump nav menu items from anywhere?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46262/73) for a plugin to collect these items for later usage.
- In [Dynamically link to the latest post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59918/73) I showed a case where the ID is empty. Prepare for that in your code. :)

Comment: Thanks @toscho. I ended up doing something a bit differently, but it still needs work. http://pastebin.com/TDQiQnAk