# Building Menus with the latest posts included

Tags: menus, sub-menu, recent-posts

Im looking to build a menu system much like that off the huffington post or washington post, with links on one side and the latest articles or other dynamic content on another.

Before i go crazy and try this, does anyone know if there are plugins that provide this functionality, i cannot find any but maybe some of you awesome folks know of some?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59918/73)?

Comment: I was looking at that before i asked. Its the idea i want but not the functionality. Im looking to show multiple (say 5) most recent posts, only only for top level categories, and inside the dropdown menu, not on the main menu. I suspect I can use this as a starting point.